# C header file macro

Tags: c

```
ML_EXTERN _ML_AB ML_FUNC(M_Process)
#ifdef ML_ARGS_LIST
(
  ML_INT i
);
#endif
```

If I am creating interfaces for vendors (who need to implement those interfaces) why would I have the above declaration in my API? I think it's called a macro - why wouldn't I just declare the function like "normal": `int M_Process();`? What is the difference and what do the various parts of the declaration above do?

Comment: Macros like this allow for platform-dependent injection of calling conventions and other kind of linkage decorations (e.g. library import/export). E.g. when you compile the library itself, you'd inject an "export" decoration, and when you compile client code, it'd be an "import" decoration.

Comment: @KerrekSB Would you mind posting an answer and explaining with an example of each? I think you're saying that for an application developer, you would "inject the import decoration" when you compile your code. And for a vendor implementing this API you'd "inject an export decoration" when compiling your code. However I don't see how that works (what does "injecting the decoration" look like?) or why you'd need this declaration to do that. As an application developer I'd usually simply #include the header files then define the functions from the header files. Thanks for posting.

Comment: @KyleM I don't think it's as much for the application developer - as it is for the the library developer to handle X compiler library export.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you don't have time to do an example, do you know what kind of tutorials/articles I should be looking for? Or what design pattern this is called?

Comment: @JustinMeiners Then why is the above declaration from my post required for the vendor to export their functions? I realize that the vendor needs to export their functions to make them visible in a DLL... I just don't get what the above declaration does and why it's needed...\

Comment: @KyleM often you see something to the essence of. `if VC (define EXPORT __exportVC) else if GCC (define EXPORT __exportGCC) extern EXPORT myFunc();` The keywords are different for each compiler and this format allows you to handle compiler differences easily by redefining the EXPORT macro.

Comment: @JustinMeiners Don't forget that the macros allow for cross-platform portability, as well.  On Linux, shared libraries don't require special export declarations, but this has not always been true for all flavors of Unix, and is not true in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros like these are largely added for compatibility with different C compilers.  You'll find this in code from the 1980s and 1990s for compilers that were either K&R compliant (predated ANSI C), or lacked various features.

You'd have to read the macro definitions to be absolutely sure, but there are some common patterns with this kind of thing.  The macros break into a few types:

#### Linkage conventions

By defining `ML_EXTERN`, the API can support different [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (e.g., stdcall, fastcall, etc.), or different kinds of external linkage (e.g., Microsoft's [`dllexport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).  This provides compiler compatibility and cross-platform compatibility while not substantially affecting code readability.

#### Consistent type sizes

The number of bits in types like `int`, `short`, and `long` are platform-dependent, although there are some restrictions.  Many libraries that predate the standard `inttypes.h` and `stdint.h` headers use macros or typedefs to ensure that their types will be the same size on all platforms.  `ML_INT` is either a macro or a typedef to an appropriately-sized integer type.

#### Prototype support

Many compilers in the 80s were built to the K&R standard for C and do not support ANSI function prototypes.  The `ML_FUNC` and `ML_ARGS_LIST` macros address this.

If prototypes are supported, then `ML_ARGS_LIST` will be defined and `ML_FUNC(x)` would expand to `x`.  The full expansion, ignoring the `ML_EXTERN` and `_ML_AB` would be:

```
M_Process(ML_INT i)
```

If the compiler does not support prototypes, then `ML_FUNC(x)` will expand to `x()` and the prototype argument list will be ommited.  The full expansion would be:

```
M_Process()
```

In K&R C, all arguments are coerced according to the rules, and parameter variables are defined where the function is defined, not declared.  See [Wikipedia's entry on C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) for some details of the differences in C versions.

Comment: I hope your compiler supports at least prototypes :)

Comment: So to summarize this thread so far -- the macros help support functionality from different compilers that have different standards for how functions can be declared. Also, the library developer can put a special "export" declaration into the header files, which will then somehow combine this "export" declaration with the macros in order to properly export functions in the DLL.

Comment: @KyleM  That's basically it.  The world used to be a much messier place, and libraries would use macros to try and maximize portability.  The [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/index.html) has a section on portable C/C++ programming that's either enlightening or terrifying, depending on your perspective.